# Ruby Error - undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Ruby class that contains two methods. The first method opens the file, and the second method works with the data read from the file.

Note that this is not the original code that I am working on, but one to demonstrate the issue I'm having.

```
class Example

  def load_json(filepath)
     require 'json'
     file = File.read(path-to-file)
     file_data = JSON.parse(file)
  end

  def read_data(tag)
    load_json(tag)
    #code to read and work with the data from file_data 
  end

end
```

When I try that, it gives me the following error:

```
`file_data': undefined local variable or method `file_data'
```

I'm a total Ruby beginner.

Comment: replace `read_json` with `load_json`?

Comment: Edited the question. Was a typo.

Comment: That typo was causing the `undefined local variable or method 'read_json'` error.

Comment: No I meant, that was a typo made when I wrote the question. :)

Comment: Then where is that 'read_json' error coming from?  Include the backtrace and the code where the backtrace indicates the problem is.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I cut&pasted & ran your code, and it doesn't give any errors whatsoever (apart from the obvious `undefined local variable or method `path'` in line 5).

Comment: I have a different code, this one is to demonstrate the issue I'm having, and the answer posted by Doon fixed it for me. Apparently, file_data should not be local, and when I added @ to it, everything worked just fine for me in the original code that I am working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `file_data` to be `@file_data` in both functions, which makes it an instance variable.  Without the @ it is only local to the function, and goes out of scope when the function exits/returns.

```
class Example

  def load_json(filepath)
     require 'json'
     file = File.read(path-to-file)
     @file_data = JSON.parse(file)
  end

  def read_data(tag)
    load_json(tag)
    #code to read and work with the data from @file_data 
  end

end
```